# Get corresponding type when using Typescript's keyof?

Tags: typescript

I want to do something like this:

```
interface StateItem<T extends StateItemType>{
    id: string;
    values: {
        [key in keyof T]: Provider<corresponding typeof T>
    }
}

type Primitive = number | string | Position; 

interface StateItemType {
    [key: string] : Primitive; 
}

interface Mover extends StateItemType  {
    center: Position; 
    speed: number; 
    vector: Position; 
    accruedVector: Position;
}

const mover : StateItem<Mover> = {
    id: "123", 
    values: {
         center: createRandomPosition(), 
         speed: createRandomNumber(), 
         vector: createRandomPosition(), 
         accruedVector: createRandomPosition(), 
    }
}
```

That is, given an interface `T` which is a straightforward key:type map, when I create a `StateItem<T>` an instances of that must have a `values` object that contains all of those keys, and `Provider<type>` instances.

How would I do this?

Comment: Not sure, what you mean by corresponding typeof T.  For each `key` in the mapped type from `values`, you can access the corresponding value for `key` with `T[key]` like `values: {
        [key in keyof T]: Provider<T[key]>
    }`. Is that what you want?

Comment: What exactly is Provider?

Comment: @ford04 - Yes, I've just seen that that works. I didn't realise that the `key` reference is retained for the rest of the line. If you like post that as an answer - and would be useful is explaining exactly how the `key` reference is retained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following type to access the property value type for each key in `T`:

```
interface StateItem<T extends StateItemType>{
    id: string;
    values: {
        [key in keyof T]: Provider<T[key]>>
    }
}
```

The construct `{[key in keyof T]: Provider<T[key]>}` is called a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types). It creates a new type, where each key in `T` is mapped to a new property value type.

`key` is a type variable and points to the currently used key, similar to a [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop, where you can access each property successively with an index variable. `key` can also be used in the property value type declaration part of the mapped type. By the way: you can rename `key` as you like, often short names like `P` or `K` are used to distinguish those index type variables from real types.

Inside the mapped type, `T[key]` would [lookup](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) the property value type for the currently accessed property key hold by `key` variable inside `T` (the typed to be mapped). So, something like this effectively is a NOOP:

```
type T1 = { foo: string; bar: number }
type T2 = {[K in keyof T1]: T1[K]} // not very interesting type...
```

Hope, it makes things a bit more clear!